# How to avoid text from moving away from image when resizing the browser?

Tags: html, css

I have been trying to keep the text inside the image when I resize the browser. I've tried floating it as well.

```
<div class="image">
<img src="background2.jpg">
<h1>Hello</h1>
</div>
```

And here is the CSS

```
.image img{
    width: 90%;
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
    position: relative;
}
h1{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%; 
    left: 50%; 
    width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want the parent element (`.image`) to be `position: relative` so that it's what the `h1` will be absolutely positioned relative to. You can also give it the width and margin that center it at 90% of the page. Then make the image 100% width of the parent, and use `top: 50%; left: 50%; transform: translate(-50%,-50%);` to absolutely center the text vertically and horizontally.

```css
.image {
  width: 90%;
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
}

.image img {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}

.stuff {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="image">
  <img src="http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/img/fonz1.png">
  <div class="stuff">
    <h1>Hello</h1>
    <h2>Foobar</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked but i wanted to know how? was it because the transform you did at the h1?

Comment: @jcdumdumaya no, you had `position: relative` on the `img` - that won't center the text realtive to the image because the image isn't a parent of the text. It's the combination of the things I described in my answer to you. Try taking them out and seeing how they affect the layout.

Comment: I tried taking out the transform and when i resize it it moves a little bit

Comment: @jcdumdumaya ok, is there a problem and/or do you have a question?

Comment: can I ask about 2 elements? I inserted an h2 in the same div and now its moving.

Comment: @jcdumdumaya I'm assuming you don't know what I'm doing and/or you aren't a developer? If you don't know and you just want an answer, the `h1` is absolutely positioned over the image in my CSS because that's your code. Inserting an `h2` wouldn't work with this code because that isn't how it was written. You didn't have an `h2` in your example. If you want to stuff a bunch of text over the image, absolutely position a parent element, then put all the text in that element that you want to appear over the image. Updated my answer with that.

Comment: @jcdumdumaya that said, assuming you are a developer, I would encourage you to figure that out on your own or ask a new question if you can't figure it out. It's bad etiquette to bring up new issues in the comments that are beyond the scope of your original question.

Answer (score 0):

You can try making the image the background of the parent div:

```
<div class="image">
  <h1>Hello</h1>
</div>
```

The css would look something like this:

```
.image {
  background: url('background2.jpg') no-repeat center center;
  background-size: cover;
}
```